# CSS - sticky element in smallest (by height) <td> not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, css-position, sticky

If sticky element placed inside smallest (by height) `<td>` but `position:sticky` and `position:-webkit-sticky` property for element doesn't work in Safari (desktop and mobile).

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldg820c7/3/

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td valign = "top">
        <div style="height:1000px; width:100px; border:1px solid red;"></div>
    </td>
    <td valign = "top">
        <div style="height:10px; width:100px; border:1px solid black; position:sticky; position: -webkit-sticky; top:10px; "></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use `position:fixed` instead.

Comment: This is a simplified case, `position:fixed` is not suitable for me.

Comment: @Vv. you should never use `div` inside `td` and also when you say it is not working in safari, like what does that mean and what is the expected output?

Comment: It doesn’t matter if it is a `div` or a `button` - both don't work.

I need the `position: sticky` behavior - simple examples here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by wrapping `position:sticky` `div` into another `div`, the height of which is set using javascript equal to the height of parent `td`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td valign = "top">
        <div style="height:1000px; width:100px; border:1px solid red;"></div>
    </td>
    <td id="td" valign = "top">
        <div id="wrap">
        <div style="height:10px; width:100px; border:1px solid black; position:sticky; position: -webkit-sticky; top:10px; "></div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
$('#wrap').height( $('#td').height() );
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mqvpb1r5/